# How to schedule an AutoIt script to run daily?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, autoit

I have a script that captures the screen to an image. I'd like it to run everyday at 4PM. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to [Task Scheduler](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7). Alternatively a timer in AutoIt script itself is possible, but in turn requires the script's scheduled (or manual) startup on system start.