# Take screenshot every 60 seconds

Tags: windows, loops, while-loop, screenshot, autoit

This script should create an automated screen capture from a specific window even in background. The function to take a screenshot works but I have problems to put it together so I can compile and run it.

```
#include <GDIPlus.au3>
#include <WindowsConstants.au3>
#include <ScreenCapture.au3>
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <AutoItConstants.au3>

; Press ESC to exit script
HotKeySet("{ESC}", "On_Exit")

Global $Paused, $Runner
Global $fNot_1_Vis = True, $iBegin = 0
Global $sAutoIt_Path = StringRegExpReplace(@AutoItExe, "(^.*\\)(.*)", "\1")
_GDIPlus_Startup()
Global $handle = WinGetHandle("[HANDLE:NOTEPAD]") ; This is the Handle from the window to capture found manual under WindowInfo! ;
_GDIPlus_Shutdown() ; Shuts down the process. ;
_ScreenCapture_SetJPGQuality(100);max image quality
$scrFile = @ScriptDir & "\screenshot - " & @MDAY & @MON & @YEAR & '-' & @HOUR &@MIN& @SEC & ".png" ;save file with name format;
_ScreenCapture_CaptureWnd($scrFile, "[ACTIVE]", -1, -1, -1, -1, 0)

Opt("TrayAutoPause", 0)

HotKeySet("{PAUSE}", "TogglePause")
HotKeySet("{ESC}", "Terminate")
HotKeySet("{F9}", "Capture_Window")

Func On_Exit()
    Exit
EndFunc

While 1
    Sleep(100)
WEnd
;;;;;;;;

Func TogglePause()
    $Paused = Not $Paused
    While $Paused
        Sleep(100)
        ToolTip('Script is "Paused"', 0, 0)
    WEnd
    ToolTip("")
EndFunc   ;==>TogglePause

Func Terminate()
    Exit 0
EndFunc   ;==>Terminate

Func Capture_Window($hWnd, $w, $h)
    $Runner = Not $Runner
    While $Runner
 Sleep(3000)
    If Int($w) < 1 Then Return SetError(2, 0, 0)
    If Int($h) < 1 Then Return SetError(3, 0, 0)
    Local Const $hDC_Capture = _WinAPI_GetDC(HWnd($hWnd))
    Local Const $hMemDC = _WinAPI_CreateCompatibleDC($hDC_Capture)
    Local Const $hHBitmap = _WinAPI_CreateCompatibleBitmap($hDC_Capture, $w, $h)
    Local Const $hObjectOld = _WinAPI_SelectObject($hMemDC, $hHBitmap)
    DllCall("gdi32.dll", "int", "SetStretchBltMode", "hwnd", $hDC_Capture, "uint", 4)
    DllCall("user32.dll", "int", "PrintWindow", "hwnd", $hWnd, "handle", $hMemDC, "int", 0)
    _WinAPI_DeleteDC($hMemDC)
    _WinAPI_SelectObject($hMemDC, $hObjectOld)
    _WinAPI_ReleaseDC($hWnd, $hDC_Capture)
    Local Const $hFullScreen = WinGetHandle("[TITLE:Program Manager;CLASS:Progman]")
    Local Const $aFullScreen = WinGetPos($hFullScreen)
    Local Const $c1 = $aFullScreen[2] - @DesktopWidth, $c2 = $aFullScreen[3] - @DesktopHeight
    Local Const $wc1 = $w - $c1, $hc2 = $h - $c2
    WEnd
 EndFunc
```

Answer (score 0):

You want it to do a screenshot every 60 seconds, but you don't have any code to do so.

Replace your main loop

```
While 1
    Sleep(100)
WEnd
```

with something like

```
While 1
    Sleep(60*1000)
    Capture_Window($handle, $w, $h)
WEnd
```

Of course `$handle`, `$w` and `$h` should be set properly before. You may also want to decrease the sleep time by the approximate time, `Capture_Window` needs.

Comment: Sorry but i am unable to follow your instructions, i don´t know how i can do this. Everytime i try to give the loop Capture_Window($handle, $w, $h) it gives me erros back.

Comment: are those variables defined? (they are not in your code)

Answer (score -1):

> … i have problems to put the automatic shot every 60s …

Windows Task Scheduler may be used. Example using AutoIt (executes on each new minute):

```
#include <ScreenCapture.au3>

Global Const $g_iDelay     = 10
Global Const $g_sSeconds   = '00'
Global Const $g_sFileName  = @ScriptDir & '\screenshot_%s.jpg'
Global Const $g_sKeyExit   = '{ESC}'

Global       $g_bStateExit = False

Main()

Func Main()
    Local $sTimeStamp = ''
    Local $sFileName  = ''

    HotKeySet($g_sKeyExit, 'SetStateExit')

    While Not $g_bStateExit

        If Not (@SEC = $g_sSeconds) Then

            Sleep($g_iDelay)
            ContinueLoop

        EndIf

        $sTimeStamp = @YEAR & @MON & @MDAY & @HOUR & @MIN & @SEC
        $sFileName  = StringFormat($g_sFileName, $sTimeStamp)
        _ScreenCapture_Capture($sFileName)

    WEnd

    Exit
EndFunc

Func SetStateExit()

    $g_bStateExit = True

EndFunc
```

Simply replace `_ScreenCapture_Capture()` (since "*take a Screenshot itself works*").

[Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29480070/4157124).